# Determine what the automorphism group of $\Bbb Z_{7^3}$ looks like.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, automorphism-group, free-abelian-group

I have a question about deciding what the automorphism group of $\Bbb Z_{7^3}$, that is ${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_{7^3})$, looks like.

I know that for a general prime $p$, the size of the group ${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_{p^3})$ equals the number of generators of $\Bbb Z_{p^3}$ since each automorphism is uniquely determined by the image of a generator.

Therefore, $|{\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_{p^3})|$ = $p^2(p-1)$.

So for our case, we know that $|{\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_{7^3})|$ = $7^2*6$. I got to here but I don't know how to continue.

How do I decide if ${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_{7^3})$ has a copy of $\Bbb Z_{7^2}$ or maybe two copies of  $\Bbb Z_{7}$?

I think I know that it would have a copy of $\Bbb Z_6$ and not of $S_3$ because $\Bbb Z_{7^3}$ is cyclic, but I'm not quite sure...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$\Bbb{Z}_{7^3}$ is a cyclic group so it's automorphism group is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_{7^3}^{\times}$ (the set of multiplicatively invertible elements).

Comment: How do I decide what would that group look like? I need to find its direct decomposition to groups.

Comment: @Micheal21 $\Bbb{Z}_{7^3}^{\times}$ is a **cyclic** group of order $\varphi(7^3)=7^3-7^2=294$.

Comment: How do you know that $Aut(Z_{7^3})$ is also cyclic?

Comment: @Micheal21 $\text{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}_{7^3})$ is**isomorphic** to the group $\Bbb{Z}_{7^3}^{\times}$. So whatever structure this group has will also be the structure of the automorphism group. Now this latter group happens to be cyclic. So our automorphism group (being isomorphic) has to be cyclic as well.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

We have $${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_n)\cong U(n),$$ where $U(n)$ is the group of units modulo $n$.

Reference:

*"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition),"* by J. A. Gallian, page 137.